# System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: sql, asp.net, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em asp.net, onde estou tentando realizar esta inserção no banco. Porem quando tento realizar este comando, acaba informando essa mensagem de erro: "System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

```
[WebMethod]
public void InsertUsuario(string usuario, string senha, string nome, string dtnasc, string fone, string email, int oab, string endereco, string bairro, string cep, int codcidade, string cpf, string cnpj)
{
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string chav = "asfasdf";
                DateTime dateFromString = DateTime.Parse(dtnasc, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Into Usuarios (IdUsuario, Usuario, Senha, Nome, Chave, DtNasc, Fone, Email, OAB, Endereco, Bairro, CEP, CodCidade, CPF, CNPJ) VALUES ((Select MAX(idusuario)+1 from Usuarios), '" + usuario + "', '" + senha + "', '" + nome + "', '" + chav + "', '"+dateFromString+"', '" + fone + "', '" + email + "', " + oab + ", '" + endereco + "', '" + bairro + "', '" + cep + "', " + codcidade + ", '" + cpf  + "','"+cnpj+"')");
                Console.WriteLine(dateFromString.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
}
```

Esse é o banco criado:

```
Create table Usuarios (
IdUsuario              int  not null,
Usuario                varchar(30) not null,
Senha                  varchar(30) not null,
Nome                   varchar(50) not null,
Chave                  varchar(18) not null,
DtNasc                 date null,
Fone                   varchar(15) not null,
Email                  varchar(70) null,
OAB                    int null,
Endereco               varchar (100) null,
Bairro                 varchar (80) null,
CEP                    varchar (9) null,
CodCidade              int null,
CPF                    varchar (20) null,
CNPJ                   varchar (20) null
primary key (IdUsuario)
)
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery: propriedade Connection n&#227;o foi inicializada. em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async) em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(Tas‌​kCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: no seu web.config declarou a string ?

Comment: Declarei sim, já fiz outros testes no banco e a conexão esta funcionando corretamente.

Comment: em qual linha exatamente ocorre o erro ?

Comment: Ai que esta o porem, nao diz em qual linha que esta o erro:

System.NullReferenceException: Refer&#234;ncia de objeto n&#227;o definida para uma inst&#226;ncia de um objeto.
   em OniPresenteAPI.oni.InsertUsuario(String usuario, String senha, String nome, String dtnasc, String fone, String email, Int32 oab, String endereco, String bairro, String cep, Int32 codcidade, String cpf, String cnpj) 

essa é a mensagem de erro completa

Comment: print com a imagem do erro ?

Answer (score -1):

Você não está atribuindo a conexão ao command,

tente fazer assim:

```
string sql = @"INSERT Into Usuarios (IdUsuario, Usuario, Senha, Nome, Chave, DtNasc, Fone, Email, OAB, Endereco, Bairro, CEP, CodCidade, CPF, CNPJ) VALUES ((Select MAX(idusuario)+1 from Usuarios), '" + usuario + "', '" + senha + "', '" + nome + "', '" + chav + "', '"+dateFromString+"', '" + fone + "', '" + email + "', " + oab + ", '" + endereco + "', '" + bairro + "', '" + cep + "', " + codcidade + ", '" + cpf  + "','"+cnpj+"')";


string chav = "asfasdf";
DateTime dateFromString = DateTime.Parse(dtnasc, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
Console.WriteLine(dateFromString.ToString());
conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Agora apresenta essa mensagem

System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery: propriedade Connection n&#227;o foi inicializada.
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: edita sua pergunta e coloque o código atual como está